# How to append array in file

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I am trying to write main array in a file and this main array contain sub array . Now whenever I write main array the sub array get overwritten .
Below is my code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        char fname[10];
        printf("Type your first name:\n");
        scanf("%s",fname);
        NSString *firstname = [[NSString alloc] init];
        firstname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:fname];

        char lname[10];
        printf("Type your last name:\n");
        scanf("%s",lname);
        NSString *lastname = [[NSString alloc] init];
        lastname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:lname];

        long mnumber = 0;
        printf("Enter your register mobile number:\n");
        scanf("%ld",&mnumber);
        NSNumber *mobilenumber = [NSNumber numberWithLong:mnumber];

        long anumber = 0;
        printf("Enter your account number:\n");
        scanf("%ld",&anumber);
        NSNumber *accountnumber = [NSNumber numberWithLong:anumber];

        NSURL *docdir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDesktopDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

        NSURL *filepath = [docdir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Dexter_apps/filetesting/data.plist"];

        NSArray *data = @[firstname,lastname,mobilenumber,accountnumber];
        NSMutableArray *mainarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        mainarray = @[data];

        [mainarray writeToURL:filepath atomically:NO];


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297709/how-to-append-nsmutable-array-to-existing-file](How to append NSMutable array to existing file) "You then need to firstly read the file into a mutable array, append the new contents to the array just read, and write it to disk afterwards"

Comment: @Willeke Why read it in?  That's a terrible idea if you care about core memory size.  It's just a case of marshalling the array data to the format used within the file and appending to an existing file.

Comment: Pasted the link the wrong way around: [How to append NSMutable array to existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297709/how-to-append-nsmutable-array-to-existing-file)

Comment: @trojanfoe What is the data format of the file? How do you add a subarray to the main array in the file?

Comment: The file format has not been specified.  That will make a difference to how the appending can be performed, whether the original file needs to be read in first, or whether the file can be appended in-place.  So the question cannot be answered properly.

Comment: Guys, I created new mutable array and read the content of file in this new array and after that appending the array with input and then writing it to file . And this steps solve my issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe the NSArray writeToFile: method uses a property list, likely the XML format given the use of NSNumbers.  You would have to parse that by hand, as well as a lot of other painful work -- not worth it.  Reading in the whole array and writing it back out is the correct solution --  writeToFile:atomically: method is simplistic, best used with smallish data sets. A different format (like appending CSV lines to an existing file) could work, but you'd have to write your own parser, and format the values by hand, which is more work.

Comment: @CarlLindberg Well "correct" depends on the size of the file.  If the data doesn't fit into core then it won't work.  Therefore if appending is a common operation a different file-format would need to be employed rather than relying on the default format.

Comment: @trojanfoe -- Sure, but that is just saying if the full data cannot fit into core, then you shouldn't be using NSArray's writeToFile: method in the first place, and you'll need to find another way to write out the data.  Since they were using writeToFile: in the first place, I was making that assumption.  For large data, yes you would need to build an entirely different solution.